# Как 3х мерную матрицу привести к 2 мерной?

Tags: python, numpy

Здравствуйте, есть 3х мерная матрица, надо ее привести к двухмерной, таким образом чтобы элементы 1 уровня добавились в конец элементов 2 уровня, и тем самым 2 уровень стал первым.

```
x,y,z = 2,4,8
a=np.arange(x*y*z).reshape(2,4,8)


array([[[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]],

[[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
[56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]])
```

Как получить

```
array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
[ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [numpy.concatenate(..., axis=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

Исходная матрица:

```
In [1]: a
Out[1]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]],

       [[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
        [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]])

In [2]: a.shape
Out[2]: (2, 4, 8)
```

Решение:

```
In [3]: np.concatenate(a, axis=1)
Out[3]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]])

In [4]: np.concatenate(a, axis=1).shape
Out[4]: (4, 16)
```